# Within a python script, check syntactic correctness of C code in str format

Tags: python, c, clang, llvm

Necessarily within a python program and given an `str` variable that contains C code, I want to check *fast* if this code is syntactically correct, or not. Essentially, I only need to pass it through the compiler's front end.

My current implementation uses a temp file to dump the string and calls a clang process with subprocess (non-working code below to illustrate my solution). This is very slow for my needs.

```
src = "int main(){printf("This is a C program\n"); return 0;}"
with open(temp_file, 'w') as f:
  f.write(src)
  cmd = ["clang", abs_path(f), flags]
  subprocess.Popen(cmd)
  ## etc..
```

After looking around, I found out about `clang.cindex` module (`pip clang`), which I tried out. After reading a bit the [main module](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/bindings/python/clang/cindex.py), lines 2763-2837 (specifically line 2828) led me to the conclusion that the following code snippet will do what I need:

```
import clang.cindex
......
try:
  unit = clang.cindex.TranslationUnit.from_source(temp_code_file, ##args, etc.)
  print("Compiled!")
except clang.cindex.TranslationUnitLoadError:
  print("Did not compile!")
```

However, it seems that even if the source file contains obvious syntactic errors, an exception is not raised. Anyone knows what am I missing to make this work ?

On a general context, any suggestions on how to do this task as fast as possible would be more than welcome. Even with `clang.cindex`, I cannot get away from writing my string-represented code to a temp file, which may be an additional overhead. Writing a python parser could solve this but is an overkill at the moment, no matter how much I need speed.

Comment: didn't quickly find the doco, but don't you think `unit` might expose success or failure of  `from_source()`?

Comment: @DanielFarrell I did, though `unit` only holds an `Index` object. `Index` can call `parse()`, in which a `TranslationUnit.from_source()` is created. Therefore, unless I'm missing something, it seems to me that the only interaction with 'erroneous' behavior is the exception in line 2828.

Comment: have you seen the line 2798 "It is the caller's responsibility to check tu.diagnostics for errors." where i suppose tu is the TranslationUnit ?

Comment: @BrunoO, good comment, it looks like iterating `diagnostics @property` gives the compilation status of the input src. This is actually the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compilation itself *succeeds* even if the file has syntax errors. Consider the following example:

```py
import clang.cindex

with open('broken.c', 'w') as f:
    f.write('foo bar baz')

unit = clang.cindex.TranslationUnit.from_source('broken.c')
for d in unit.diagnostics:
    print(d.severity, d)
```

Run it and you will get

```
3 broken.c:1:1: error: unknown type name 'foo'
3 broken.c:1:8: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
```

The `severity` member of is an `int`, with the value from the `enum CXDiagnosticSeverity` with values

- CXDiagnostic_Ignored = 0
- CXDiagnostic_Note = 1
- CXDiagnostic_Warning = 2
- CXDiagnostic_Error = 3
- CXDiagnostic_Fatal = 4

Comment: good post, that is the right solution indeed! Thank you. Will mark this answer as accepted soon, unless someone comes up with a faster checking solution, maybe getting rid of dumping string-code to a temp file.

Comment: @FoivosTs that's unlikely to help much as there are so many other files to read from anyway.

Comment: You do not need to create a temporary file. You can pass in any fake filename (with proper file ending) as the filename parameter, and pass a list of key-value pairs containing the same file name and the source code string like this:

`result = clang.cindex.TranslationUnit.from_source("filename.cpp", unsaved_files=[("filename.cpp", "some c++ code")])`